# Why am I getting access denied on assets from an aws s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, craftcms

I have created an s3 bucket in aws and added the correct permissions and user group etc. I have added the below policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        }
    ]
}
```

I uploaded the assets from a local folder via ftp to the bucket using transmit ftp client which was fine. I have then set the bucket up on craft cms as an asset source. I can upload files to s3 via the cms fine with no issues and view the image fine but when I try to access an image on the front end that was uploaded via the ftp I get access denied error 403:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>96E15AB155C47209</RequestId>
<HostId>
our-hist-id-here
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Is this a policy issue?

Thanks

Comment: Does the bucket owner have full control over the files that were uploaded (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-access/)?

Comment: Ah no this is useful

Comment: Does the user have any other S3-related policies? For example, there might be a policy that has an explicit `Deny`, which will override an `Allow`.